# adding submenu in pyqt QWidget

Tags: pyqt4, pyside, qwidget, qmenu, qmenubar

I know its very basic question but I am little bit confused, probably I am forgetting something.

I am trying to add a sub menu "Preview" to the "Tools" in the QMenuBar()

so far this is what I am trying to do

```
tools = fileMenu.addMenu('&Tools')
prevAction = QtGui.QAction('Preview',self)
prevInNuke = QtGui.QAction("Using &Nuke",prevAction)
tools.addAction(prevAction)
prevAction.addAction(prevInNuke)
```

but I guess this is not the correct way to add a sub menu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sub menu should be a `QMenu`, not `QAction`:

```py
tools = fileMenu.addMenu('&Tools')
prevMenu = QtGui.QMenu('Preview',self)
prevInNuke = QtGui.QAction("Using &Nuke",prevAction)
tools.addMenu(prevMenu)
prevAction.addAction(prevInNuke)
```

It can be a bit more simple if you used convenience methods:

```py
tools = fileMenu.addMenu('&Tools')
prevMenu = tools.addMenu('Preview')
prevAction = prevMenu.addAction('Using &Nuke')
```

Comment: Thanks for including both versions!  Convenience methods are certainly nice when you can use them (but you can't always use them).